# Refactor passport local strategy using promisy. Problem with .catch()

Tags: express, error-handling, promise, this

In an express + passport + local strategy app, I use `bcrypt` to hash password, this is working:

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

familySchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var family = this;
  var SALT_FACTOR = 14;

  if (!family.isModified('password')) return next();

  bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    bcrypt.hash(family.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      family.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});
```

Then I refactored using `promisify` and `async/await`:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const util = require('util');
const bcryptGenSalt = util.promisify(bcrypt.genSalt);
const bcryptHash = util.promisify(bcrypt.hash);

familySchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
  var family = this;
  const SALT_FACTOR = 14;
  if (!family.isModified('password')) return next();
  const salt = await bcryptGenSalt(SALT_FACTOR).catch(next);
  const hash = await bcryptHash(family.password, salt, null).catch(next);
  family.password = hash;
  next();
});
```

- Is this refactoring actually correct?
- How can I double check that errors in `bcryptGenSalt` or `bcryptHash` are caught correctly? Is there a way to somehow "force" `bcryptGenSalt` into throwing an error, for testing?
- Next step, how can I remove the two `.catch(next)`, using a `wrapAsync` util function:

`wrapAsync.js`:

```
module.exports = fn => (req, res, next) => fn(req, res, next).catch(next);
```

Following attempt is not working, error: `family.isModified()` is not a function, (probably because the `this` is not right anymore).
And what to do with the arguments of wrapAsync, as `next` should be the 3rd argument?

```
familySchema.pre(
  'save',
  wrapAsync(async function(req, res, next) {
    var family = this;
    const SALT_FACTOR = 14;
    debugger;
    if (!family.isModified('password')) return next();
    const salt = await bcryptGenSalt(SALT_FACTOR);
    const hash = await bcryptHash(family.password, salt, null);
    family.password = hash;
    next();
  })
);
```

Comment: I just realized that I'm using `bcrypt-nodejs` package instead of official `bcrypt`! And bcrypt support promises. As per bcrypt documentation ( https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js#with-promises ), bcrypt will automatically output a promise if no callback function is provided. So I can remove the `promisify` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The refactoring is not correct, because after the `.catch` statements, the rest of the function will continue to run. So if for instance `bcryptGenSalt` throws an error, `next` is called (because of `.catch(next)`) but it will also continue with the next line of code, until the end of the function (where `next` is called again).

Typically, in `async` functions, you use `try/catch` around statements that may throw errors:

```
familySchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
  const SALT_FACTOR = 14;
  if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();
  try {
    const salt = await bcryptGenSalt(SALT_FACTOR);
    const hash = await bcryptHash(this.password, salt, null);
    this.password = hash;
    return next();
  } catch(err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});
```

> Is there a way to somehow "force" `bcryptGenSalt` into throwing an error, for testing?

It depends on which tools you use for testing, but there are packages like [`sinon`](https://sinonjs.org/) that can stub existing functions so you can controllably make then throw errors, which you can then test for.

Comment: "because after the .catch statements, the rest of the function will continue to run"  --> Does this mean that the pattern described in https://thecodebarbarian.com/80-20-guide-to-express-error-handling should be avoided? In short, they use a wrapAsync() function to automatically add a .catch(next) to async function calls.